# NSView rotation animation with CABasicAnimation runs not correctly

Tags: cocoa, animation, cabasicanimation

I use the `CABasicAnimation` to animate the rotation of a `NSView`. The code runs well on iPhone and now I want to plant it to the cocoa.

```
    [self.secondView setWantsLayer:YES];
    CABasicAnimation *anim2 = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation"];
    anim2.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear];
    anim2.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0];
    anim2.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:-((360*M_PI)/180)];
    anim2.repeatCount = HUGE_VALF;
    anim2.duration = 8.0;
    [self.secondView.layer addAnimation:anim2 forKey:@"transform"];
```

When it runs, the view's frame seems to be covered,like below:

[image]

You can see the four vertexes are not shown.

As I'm not so familiar with cocoa, could anyone tell me where is the problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I set the configuration in the nib file:
the secondView is a `NSImageView`, and makes the view in the `Core Animation Layer`, but leaves the `Image Well` unselected.

But could anyone how to make the configurations in code?
I can't find anything in the `NSImageView` Document.